# add two different queries result into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-insert, rdbms

I have two different query (having same no. of columns in result).
I want to put both in one table.

for example i have following table:

```
id     country     salary 
1        us        10000

2        uk        25000

3        us        35000

4        uk        31000

5        uk        26000
```

now I have following queries:

Query 1 :

```
select * from table where country='us';
```

and

Query 2 :

```
select * from table where country='uk';
```

i have one final table having six columns like:

```
 id1   |country1  |  salary 1 |  id2  |  country2 |  salary2
```

Now, i want to put both queries result in this table so following output should be shown:

Desired Output:

```
id1   |country1  |  salary 1  |  id2   |  country2 |  salary2 
 1    |     us   |   10000    |    2   |      uk   |   25000

 3    |     us   |   35000    |    4   |      uk   |   31000

null  |   null   |   null     |    5   |      uk   |   26000
```

I have tried this but it doesn't combine the result:

```
insert into table (id1,country1,salary1)
select id,country,salary
from table1
where country='us';
```

and

```
insert into table (id2,country2,salary2)
select id,country,salary
from table1
where country='uk';
```

but it gives following result:

```
id1   |country1    |  salary 1  |  id2      |  country2   |  salary2 
 1    |     us     |     10000  |     null  |     null    |     null

3     |    us      |    35000   |    null   |    null     |    null

null  |   null     |   null     |   2       |    uk       |    25000

null  |   null     |   null     |   4       |    uk       |    31000

null  |   null     |   null     |   5       |    uk       |    26000
```

Please help me out:

Comment: You can use joins to add them into one insert statement instead of 2 insert statements

Comment: How? I don't have idea how to use joins in insert statement.

Comment: add tag of DBMS you are using

Comment: What sort of table design is this? . What is the point of storing two distinct records in a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS support window functions, you may use them to join your intermediate result appropriately.

```
select t1.id, t1.country, t1.salary, t2.id, t2.country, t2.salary
from
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from data
  where country = 'us'
) t1
full join
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) rn
  from data
  where country = 'uk'
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6d112e7eef4ad2c98821112880033f2c)

**RESULT**

```
id      country salary  id  country salary
-------------------------------------------
1       us      10000   2   uk      25000
3       us      35000   4   uk      31000
null    null    null    5   uk      26000
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630095/reconciliation-automation-query   ..... can you help with this?